# How to create a bean bundle programatically

Tags: 7, blocks

I don't want to use features. ;)

This is my code:

> beanform.info

```
name = Bean form
description = Configure beans blocks to print forms into it.
core = 7.x
files[] = "plugins/BeanForm.class.php"
package = "Bean"
dependencies[] = "bean"
```

> beanform.module

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * beanform module file to store the hooks.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_bean_types_api_info()
 */
function beanform_bean_types_api_info() {
 return array('api' => 4);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_bean_types()
 */
function beanform_bean_types() {
  $plugins = array();
  $plugin_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'beanform') . '/plugins/bean';
  $plugins['bean_form'] = array(
    'name' => 'bean_form',
    'label' => t('Bean form'),
    'description' => t('Choose a form to print into a bean'),
    'handler' => array(
      'class' => 'BeanForm',
      'parent' => 'bean',
      // 'path' => $plugin_path,
      // 'file' => 'BeanForm.inc',
    ),
    'path' => $plugin_path,
    'file' => 'BeanForm.inc',
  );


  kpr ($plugins);

  return $plugins;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 */
function beanform_theme(){
  $items = array();
  $items ['theme_bean_form'] = array(
    'arguments' => array(
      'form' => NULL,
    ),
    'template' => 'templates/bean-form',
    'file' => 'beanform.theme.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}

?>
```

But When I go to `/admin/structure/block-types` I don't see my bean.

I don't find the problem, and I'm checking bean_examples and bean_twitter_pull to see how it should be done.

Thanks

Oskar

Comment: Obvious questions but we never know : did you clear the cache ? Does your `BeanForm` class implement the `BeanTypePluginInterface` interface ?

Comment: Hello Lovau:
Yes I have clear cache with drush, and also uninstall the module and enable again.

I have "class BeanForm extends BeanPlugin" as i'ts explain in "bean_examples".

Everything seems to be ok, but I don't get it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With bean modules it's required that if you use "name" attribute  is the same name that the $plugins key.

In my case

```
'name' => 'beanform'
```

The beast options is not use it, it's no a required attribute.

Oskar

my actual code:

```
  $plugins['beanform'] = array(
'name' => 'beanform',
'label' => t('Bean form'),
'description' => t('Choose a form to print into a bean'),
'handler' => array(
  'class' => 'BeanForm',
  'parent' => 'bean',
  'path' => $plugin_path,
  'file' => 'Beanorm.inc',
),
//   'path' => $plugin_path,
//   'file' => 'BeanForm.inc',
   'editable' => TRUE,
  );
```